# Fail with custom Action Bar by using Android Action Bar Style Generator.

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I created simple project with list view. On emulator it works well. The style of Action Bar by default AppTheme. But when I generate new style through http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator resource and copy it in my  simple project it crashes. I don't know what I do wrong. I use AndroidStudio.

The process of pasting new style:
I copy downloaded files in res/ folder, then in my project I change Manifest file from AppTheme to Theme.Inter (like in my example). Next step, I copy data from style_Inter to style. That's it. I run it and it crashes.

**Log:**

```
06-16 13:41:27.912    7251-7251/com.examples.nick.listviewexample E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.examples.nick.listviewexample/com.examples.nick.listviewexample.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:151)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:138)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:123)
        at com.examples.nick.listviewexample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: did you read the exception?

Comment: it clearly states what you need to do..

Comment: As I understood I should change in my Manifest file theme from "Theme.Inter" to "Theme.AppCompat"?  But if I do this I get another theme not my custom.

Comment: your theme should be based off `Theme.AppCompat`

Comment: You can have a theme that extends Theme.AppCompat

Comment: Update the them you generated to use Theme.AppCompa.Light as the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, your advice really helped me, Especially **maddesa**! It was simple, when I generated custom Action Bar I had to chose in Style compatibility AppCompat.

Comment: actionbarstylegenerator is deprecated. You don't need it to customize your actionbar